# Place background image in bottom corner of every slide of reveal.js

Tags: emacs, reveal.js

Is there a way to place an image (e.g. a logo) on the bottom right corner of every slide in a reveal.js presentation?

Even better if there is a way in ox-reveal(the reveal.js export mode for emacs org-mode)

Comment: Easy enough, use another css file with `body {
    background-size: 50%;
   background-image: url("foo.png");
   background-position: left top; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat; }

Answer (score 9):

Add an extra `div` to your main `.html` file and customize it with some CSS, e.g.:

```
<div id="myLogo" style="background: url(url-to-image);
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 100px;
                        right: 100px;
                        width: 100px;
                        height: 100px;"></div>
```

This will add an image with the logo in the bottom right part of the reveal.js. Just modify the CSS as you want.

Comment: In addition to this, if you would like that to be printable in the `/?print-pdf` pdf, you could add in `css/print/pdf.scss` the rule `#myLogo { z-index: 1 }`. Or adjust the pixels, too